# Can I hide the "Do you want to replace it?" warning when selecting a file with Python's tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()

Tags: python, macos, replace, tkinter, save-as

When I select a file to save to using Python's `tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()` I get a warning window, telling me that this file will be **replaced** (Both the save dialog and the warning window seem to be native OS X). But I just want to **append** some lines to the file, so it will **not** actually be replaced. 
Is there a way to tell the system/dialog to suppress the replacement warning? Or do I need to use the `askopenfilename()` method? (But since I'm saving to the file, I'd rather have the dialog show *save* and not *open*.)

Most of the information on the `tkFileDialog` module seems to be outdated. The [Effbot File Dialog site](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm) only shows two dialogs. And [this website](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) seems to indicate there is an `mode='r'` parameter, which I hoped to be able to change to `mode='a'`. But I get an `TclError: bad option "-mode"`-error.

This is the snippet from my code:

```
def _pickParamFile(self):
    filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(parent=self, 
        initialdir=self.paramFileStr.get(), 
        title="Please select Measurement Parameter file")
    if len(filename) > 0:
        self.paramFileStr.set(filename)
```

I'm using Python 2.7.3 on an OS X 10.9. Any ideas?

Comment: I try to find warning window in source code but I didn't. It has to be in Tk/Tcl not in tkinter.

Comment: Ah, ok. But I probably should have added, that the dialog seems to be a native OS X save-dialog. So I was more hoping for an option to communicate to the system dialog, that I don't care about replacing a file. Could be a system specific problem though..